# How to make a "expandable" list item in Android

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I've been trying to teach myself code in Android and have made some good progress, however I've had some difficulties finding information about some stuff I have in mind but can't translate into code, I hope your can help me with that.

The main thing I have no idea how to start with is having expandable menu items. I Made a little graphic example of what I want to do:

Headers List:

[image]

So this a scrollable list of headers, each header has some information as is (that's why they're pretty big) like a background image and some informative labels on top. When the header is tapped on then it gets pushed to the top and expands all the item info below. Likewise, when it's tapped again the info retracts and the headers list is shown again.

Also as you can see the Action Bar would be expandable, but this is secondary since I think I can make this one work on my own, however if you have comments about it please tell.

Expandable ActionBar:

[image: image2]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expandable list view is used to group list data by categories. It has the capability of expanding and collapsing the groups when user touches header.

Here , i suggest you the following links which provides the simplest example of Expandable list view...

http://javapapers.com/android/android-expandable-listview/

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

i hop this links will helpful for you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)